# What's the best way to add two elements of an object to a list without repeating them?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

**Performance, elegancy and readability** are the requirements for **"the best way"**

I have the array of dictionaries:

```
items = [
    {'id1' : 1, 'id2' : 2, 'other' : 'xxx'},
    {'id1' : 1, 'id2' : 3, 'other' : 'yyy'},
    {'id1' : 2, 'id2' : 4, 'other' : 'zzz'}
]
```

The result should be: `ids = [1,2,3,4]` (list of id1 and id2)

**Edit:**
Something like this:

```
ids = []
for item in items:
   if item.id1 not in ids:
       ids.append(item.id1)
   if item.id2 not in ids:
       ids.append(item.id2)
```

Comment: Note that the values aren't actually ordered. Unless you explicitly want `id1` and `id2`. Do you need the original order?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> set(x for y in items for x in y.values())
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

---

Update for updated question

```
>>> set(v for y in items for (k,v) in y.items() if k.startswith('id'))
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are other elements in the dictionary and just want a list of ids.

Comment: @ShankarCabus What defines an id? What other elements will there be? You haven't given us enough information here.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done pretty easily by using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten a nested [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) producing the values of the ids - we presume that all keys are going to be strings, and that starting with `"id"` specifies an id. We then make a set of those values to remove duplicates:

```
from itertools import chain

set(chain.from_iterable((value for name, value in item.items() 
                         if name.startswith("id"))
                        for item in items))
```

If you really want a list, then you could create one from the set, but in most cases, the set should be fine as-is. Note that the set has no order, so if you want an order you will need to use `sorted()`, for example.

`itertools.chain.from_iterable()` is the most efficient and readable way to flatten an iterable.

Your specification isn't clear when it comes to what an id is. If you have a set of keys which define an id, then something like this might be more appropriate as the if clause of the inner generator expression:

```
if name in {"id1", "id2"}
```

Comment: Checking membership of a set built like that that would take longer than a tuple. Even though it would be a tiny amount longer.

Comment: @jamylak True, but it generally doesn't matter either way, and I tend to use a set as it's a good habit for when the set of possibilities is huge (the only case it's likely to matter).